# how to calculate the Euclidean norm of a vector in R?

Tags: r, vector, statistics

I tried `norm`, but I think it gives the wrong result. (the norm of `c(1, 2, 3)` is `sqrt(1*1+2*2+3*3)`, but it returns `6`..

```
x1 <- 1:3
norm(x1)
# Error in norm(x1) : 'A' must be a numeric matrix
norm(as.matrix(x1))
# [1] 6
as.matrix(x1)
#      [,1]
# [1,]    1
# [2,]    2
# [3,]    3
norm(as.matrix(x1))
# [1] 6
```

Does anyone know what's the function to calculate the norm of a vector in R?

Comment: "norm" is not quite what you think it is.  Try  `sqrt(sum(x^2))` .  R does "what you expect."  `norm` and `dist` are designed to provide generalized distance calculations among rows of a matrix.

Comment: This returns a vector with the square roots of each of the components to the square, thus *1 2 3* instead of the Euclidean Norm

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This is a trivial function to write yourself:

```
norm_vec <- function(x) sqrt(sum(x^2))
```

Comment: Hey, you violated my copyright from the comment above!  I'm sending a team of RIAA lawyers after you.  :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I just went and paid some royalties, so hopefully we're all square. :)

Comment: Highly disagree with this answer.  In R you almost always want to use a built in function if one is available.  They are highly optimized.  The answer by Bernd is the correct answer.  If you come across this please scroll down and use the proper R function to perform this.

Comment: @Dalupus You should bother to benchmark the two solutions before you make such strong statements. You might find the results surprising. When I do I find that my version is around 5x faster. (Which is not to say that there may not be reasons to use `norm`. But you should actually check before speaking strongly.)

Comment: It is not really a question of speed.  Try `norm_vec(c(10^200))` and `norm(c(10^200), type="2")` to see the difference.

Comment: see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63763823/1691723) below which guard against overflow or underflow problems while computing k-norm.

Answer (score 82):

```
norm(c(1,1), type="2")     # 1.414214
norm(c(1, 1, 1), type="2")  # 1.732051
```

Comment: This is the correct answer which also allows R to use it's internal optimizations.

Comment: This takes more time than jorah's answer for me. See AbdealiJK's answer to check timings.

Comment: it's not about speed, it's about avoiding over/underflow

Comment: for destructive overflow or underflow problems, use norm with scaling. see my answer below. Look at the function definition of `knorm()`

Answer (score 25):

I was surprised that nobody had tried profiling the results for the above suggested methods, so I did that. I've used a random uniform function to generate a list and used that for repetition (Just a simple back of the envelop type of benchmark):

```
> uut <- lapply(1:100000, function(x) {runif(1000, min=-10^10, max=10^10)})
> norm_vec <- function(x) sqrt(sum(x^2))
> norm_vec2 <- function(x){sqrt(crossprod(x))}
> 
> system.time(lapply(uut, norm_vec))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.58    0.00    0.58 
> system.time(lapply(uut, norm_vec2))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.35    0.00    0.34 
> system.time(lapply(uut, norm, type="2"))
   user  system elapsed 
   6.75    0.00    6.78 
> system.time(lapply(lapply(uut, as.matrix), norm))
   user  system elapsed 
   2.70    0.00    2.73
```

It seems that taking the power and then sqrt manually is faster than the builtin `norm` for real values vectors at least. This is probably because norm internally does an SVD:

```
> norm
function (x, type = c("O", "I", "F", "M", "2")) 
{
    if (identical("2", type)) {
        svd(x, nu = 0L, nv = 0L)$d[1L]
    }
    else .Internal(La_dlange(x, type))
}
```

and the SVD function internally converts the vector into a matrix, and does more complicated stuff:

```
> svd
function (x, nu = min(n, p), nv = min(n, p), LINPACK = FALSE) 
{
    x <- as.matrix(x)
    ...
```

EDIT (20 Oct 2019):

There have been some comments to point out the correctness issue which the above test case doesn't bring out:

```
> norm_vec(c(10^155))
[1] Inf
> norm(c(10^155), type="2")
[1] 1e+155
```

This happens because large numbers are considered as infinity in R:

```
> 10^309
[1] Inf
```

So, it looks like:

> It seems that taking the power and then sqrt manually is faster than the builtin norm for real values vectors **for small numbers**.

How small? So that the sum of squares doesn't overflow.

Comment: I love how this question went from "How do I get R to do this?" to optimization. I also just made my own distance function in R then became curious what the built-in function is and why just trying "norm(v)" doesn't work haha. I also checked the speed of my function..

Comment: `library(pracma)` and `system.time(lapply(uut, Norm))` gives `0.852   0.000   0.854` for times (my `norm_vec2` times are very close to above). Also gives `Inf` for the large number test.

Answer (score 15):

```
norm(x, type = c("O", "I", "F", "M", "2"))
```

The default is `"O"`.

`"O"`, `"o"` or `"1"` specifies the one norm, (maximum absolute column sum);

"F" or "f" specifies the Frobenius norm (the Euclidean norm of x treated as if it were a vector);

```
norm(as.matrix(x1),"o")
```

The result is 6, same as `norm(as.matrix(x1))`

```
norm(as.matrix(x1),"f")
```

The result is `sqrt(1*1+2*2+3*3)`

So, `norm(as.matrix(x1),"f")` is answer.

Answer (score 4):

We can also find the norm as :

```
Result<-sum(abs(x)^2)^(1/2)
```

OR Even You can also try as:

```
Result<-sqrt(t(x)%*%x)
```

Both will give the same answer

Comment: Two simplifications: if the components of `x` are real numbers, you can replace abs(x)^2 with x^2.  Similarly, `%*%` transposes vectors as needed, so you can simplify `t(x)%*%x` to `x%*%x`.

Answer (score 3):

I'mma throw this out there too as an equivalent R expression

```
norm_vec(x) <- function(x){sqrt(crossprod(x))}
```

Don't confuse R's crossprod with a similarly named vector/[cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product). That naming is known to cause [confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162741/what-is-rs-crossproduct-function) especially for those with a physics/mechanics background.

Comment: Absolutely right, the code I wrote would do what you say but I was really just trying to highlight the vector norm computation. I'll follow Joran's naming convention here. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Answer for Euclidean length of a vector (k-norm) with scaling to avoid destructive underflow and overflow is

```
norm <- function(x, k) { max(abs(x))*(sum((abs(x)/max(abs(x)))^k))^(1/k) }
```

See below for explanation.

**1. Euclidean length of a vector with no scaling:**

---

`norm()` is a vector-valued function which computes the length of the vector. It takes two arguments such as the vector `x` of class `matrix` and the type of norm `k` of class `integer`.

```
norm <- function(x, k) {
  # x = matrix with column vector and with dimensions mx1 or mxn
  # k = type of norm with integer from 1 to +Inf
  stopifnot(k >= 1) # check for the integer value of k greater than 0
  stopifnot(length(k) == 1) # check for length of k to be 1. The variable k is not vectorized.
  if(k == Inf) {
    # infinity norm
    return(apply(x, 2, function(vec) max(abs(vec)) ))
  } else {
    # k-norm
    return(apply(x, 2, function(vec) (sum((abs(vec))^k))^(1/k) ))
  }
}

x <- matrix(c(1,-2,3,-4)) # column matrix
sapply(c(1:4, Inf), function(k) norm(x = x, k = k))
# [1] 10.000000  5.477226  4.641589  4.337613  4.000000
```

- 1-norm (10.0) converges to infinity-norm (4.0).
- k-norm is also called as "Euclidean norm in Euclidean n-dimensional space".

**Note:**
In the `norm()` function definition, for vectors with real components, the absolute values can be dropped in norm-2k or even indexed norms, where `k >= 1`.

If you are confused with the `norm` function definition, you can read each one individually as given below.

```
norm_1 <- function(x) sum(abs(x))
norm_2 <- function(x) (sum((abs(x))^2))^(1/2)
norm_3 <- function(x) (sum((abs(x))^3))^(1/3)
norm_4 <- function(x) (sum((abs(x))^4))^(1/4)
norm_k <- function(x) (sum((abs(x))^k))^(1/k)
norm_inf <- max(abs(x))
```

**2. Euclidean length of a vector with scaling to avoid destructive overflow and underflow issues:**

---

**Note-2:**
The only problem with this solution `norm()` is that it does not guard against overflow or underflow problems as alluded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39340666/1691723) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50866051/1691723).

Fortunately, someone had already solved this problem for 2-norm (euclidean length) in the blas (basic linear algebra subroutines) fortran library. A description of this problem can be found in the textbook of "Numerical Methods and Software by Kahaner, Moler and Nash" - Chapter-1, Section 1.3, page - 7-9.

The name of the fortran subroutine is `dnrm2.f`, which handles destructive overflow and underflow issues in the `norm()` by scaling with the maximum of the vector components. The destructive overflow and underflow problem arise due to radical operation in the `norm()` function.

I will show how to implement `dnrm2.f` in `R` below.

```
#1. find the maximum among components of vector-x
max_x <- max(x)
#2. scale or divide the components of vector by max_x
scaled_x <- x/max_x
#3. take square of the scaled vector-x
sq_scaled_x <- (scaled_x)^2
#4. sum the square of scaled vector-x
sum_sq_scaled_x <- sum(sq_scaled_x)
#5. take square root of sum_sq_scaled_x
rt_sum_sq_scaled_x  <- sqrt(sum_sq_scaled_x)
#6. multiply the maximum of vector x with rt_sum_sq_scaled_x
max_x*rt_sum_sq_scaled_x
```

one-liner of the above 6-steps of `dnrm2.f` in `R` is:

```
# Euclidean length of vector - 2norm
max(x)*sqrt(sum((x/max(x))^2))
```

Lets try example vectors to compute 2-norm (see other solutions in this thread) for this problem.

```
x = c(-8e+299, -6e+299, 5e+299, -8e+298, -5e+299)
max(x)*sqrt(sum((x/max(x))^2))
# [1] 1.227355e+300

x <- (c(1,-2,3,-4))
max(x)*sqrt(sum((x/max(x))^2))
# [1] 5.477226
```

Therefore, the recommended way to implement a generalized solution for k-norm in R is that single line, which guard against the destructive overflow or underflow problems. To improve this one-liner, you can use a combination of `norm()` without scaling for a vector containing not-too-small or not-too-large components and `knorm()` with scaling for a vector with too-small or too-large components. Implementing scaling for all vectors results in too many calculations. I did not implement this improvement in `knorm()` given below.

```
# one-liner for k-norm - generalized form for all norms including infinity-norm:
max(abs(x))*(sum((abs(x)/max(abs(x)))^k))^(1/k)

# knorm() function using the above one-liner.
knorm <- function(x, k) { 
  # x = matrix with column vector and with dimensions mx1 or mxn
  # k = type of norm with integer from 1 to +Inf
  stopifnot(k >= 1) # check for the integer value of k greater than 0
  stopifnot(length(k) == 1) # check for length of k to be 1. The variable k is not vectorized.
  # covert elements of matrix to its absolute values
  x <- abs(x)
  if(k == Inf) { # infinity-norm
    return(apply(x, 2, function(vec) max(vec)))
  } else { # k-norm
    return(apply(x, 2, function(vec) {
      max_vec <- max(vec)
      return(max_vec*(sum((vec/max_vec)^k))^(1/k))
    }))
  }
}

# 2-norm
x <- matrix(c(-8e+299, -6e+299, 5e+299, -8e+298, -5e+299))
sapply(2, function(k) knorm(x = x, k = k))
# [1] 1.227355e+300

# 1-norm, 2-norm, 3-norm, 4-norm, and infinity-norm
sapply(c(1:4, Inf), function(k) knorm(x = x, k = k))
# [1] 2.480000e+300 1.227355e+300 9.927854e+299 9.027789e+299 8.000000e+299

x <- matrix(c(1,-2,3,-4))
sapply(c(1:4, Inf), function(k) knorm(x = x, k = k))
# [1] 10.000000  5.477226  4.641589  4.337613  4.000000

x <- matrix(c(1,-2,3,-4, 0, -8e+299, -6e+299, 5e+299, -8e+298, -5e+299), nc = 2)
sapply(c(1:4, Inf), function(k) knorm(x = x, k = k))
#           [,1]          [,2]          [,3]          [,4]   [,5]
# [1,]  1.00e+01  5.477226e+00  4.641589e+00  4.337613e+00  4e+00
# [2,] 2.48e+300 1.227355e+300 9.927854e+299 9.027789e+299 8e+299
```

Comment: Good answer. Your one-liner is just missing the case that `x` is the zero-vector.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a data.frame or a data.table 'DT', and want to compute the Euclidian norm (norm 2) across each row, the `apply` function can be used.

```
apply(X = DT, MARGIN = 1, FUN = norm, '2')
```

Example:

```
>DT 

        accx       accy       accz
 1: 9.576807 -0.1629486 -0.2587167
 2: 9.576807 -0.1722938 -0.2681506
 3: 9.576807 -0.1634264 -0.2681506
 4: 9.576807 -0.1545590 -0.2681506
 5: 9.576807 -0.1621254 -0.2681506
 6: 9.576807 -0.1723825 -0.2682434
 7: 9.576807 -0.1723825 -0.2728810
 8: 9.576807 -0.1723825 -0.2775187

> apply(X = DT, MARGIN = 1, FUN = norm, '2')
 [1] 9.581687 9.582109 9.581954 9.581807 9.581932 9.582114 9.582245 9.582378
```

Answer (score 1):

Following AbdealiJK's answer,

I experimented further to gain some insight.

Here's one.

```
x = c(-8e+299, -6e+299, 5e+299, -8e+298, -5e+299)
sqrt(sum(x^2))
norm(x, type='2')
```

The first result is `Inf` and the second one is `1.227355e+300` which is quite correct as I show you in the code below.

```
library(Rmpfr)
y <- mpfr(x, 120)
sqrt(sum(y*y))
```

The result is `1227354879...`. I didn't count the number of trailing numbers but it looks all right. I know there another way around this `OVERFLOW` problem which is first applying log function to all numbers and summing up, which I do not have time to implement!

Answer (score 0):

Create your matrix as column vise using cbind then the norm function works well with Frobenius norm (the Euclidean norm) as an argument.

> x1<-cbind(1:3)
>
> norm(x1,"f")

[1] 3.741657

> sqrt(1*1+2*2+3*3)

[1] 3.741657

Answer (score -1):

The Euclidean norm is calculated as the square root of the sum of the squares of the vector's elements. It is also known as the L2 or second norm.

You can calculate it using the `norm` function

```
x <- c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 14)

vector_magnitude <- norm(x, type = "2")
```