# What is R's crossproduct function?

Tags: r

I feel stupid asking, but what is the intent of R's  `crossprod` function with respect to vector inputs?    I wanted to calculate the  cross-product of two vectors in Euclidean space and mistakenly tried using `crossprod` .
One definition of the vector cross-product  is `N = |A|*|B|*sin(theta)` where theta is the angle between the two vectors.  (The direction of `N` is perpendicular to the A-B plane).  Another way to calculate it is  `N = Ax*By - Ay*Bx` .
`base::crossprod` clearly does not do this calculation, and in fact produces the vector dot-product of the two inputs `sum(Ax*Bx, Ay*By)`.

So, I can easily write my own `vectorxprod(A,B)` function, but I can't figure out what `crossprod` is doing in general.

See also [R - Compute Cross Product of Vectors (Physics)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36798301/r-compute-cross-product-of-vectors-physics/36802067)

Comment: See the `crossprod` documentation- `Vectors are promoted to single-column or single-row matrices, depending on the context.`.

Comment: @DavidRobinson I did read that, so I guess my question morphs into: what's a proper definition for a matrix cross-product and why isn't it like a Euclidean vector cross-product?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thanks for posting this, I had the same question and it has driven me crazy.  If you wrote `vectorxprod(A, B)` would you be willing to share (I guess as an answer)?  Thx.

Comment: @BryanHanson  OK, see new answer.

Comment: A bit late, but use of the term "cross product" to refer to the X'X matrix is fairly common in statistics (which is, after all, where R came from). This is a standard construction in regression applications. Googling "sum of squares and cross products" may help.

Comment: @BryanHanson, see my answer below for a simple version which also works in 3D.

Comment: Those who are from the physics and engineering world might find [pracma](https://rdrr.io/rforge/pracma/man/)'s `dot` and `cross` better named. I think I will never understand that `crossprod` means a dot product when looking at my code.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to the help function in R: crossprod (X,Y) = t(X)%*% Y is a faster implementation than the expression itself. It is a function of two matrices, and if you have two vectors corresponds to the dot product. @Hong-Ooi's comments explains why it is called crossproduct.

Comment: I'm going to check this answer as accepted and walk away slowly. After some searching, I found a monograph which actually does define a "matrix cross product" in the way R does.  http://www.utdallas.edu/~herve/abdi-MatrixAlgebra2010-pretty.pdf

Answer (score 13):

Here is a short code snippet which works whenever the cross product makes sense: the 3D version returns a vector and the 2D version returns a scalar.  If you just want simple code that gives the right answer without pulling in an external library, this is all you need.

```
# Compute the vector cross product between x and y, and return the components
# indexed by i.
CrossProduct3D <- function(x, y, i=1:3) {
  # Project inputs into 3D, since the cross product only makes sense in 3D.
  To3D <- function(x) head(c(x, rep(0, 3)), 3)
  x <- To3D(x)
  y <- To3D(y)

  # Indices should be treated cyclically (i.e., index 4 is "really" index 1, and
  # so on).  Index3D() lets us do that using R's convention of 1-based (rather
  # than 0-based) arrays.
  Index3D <- function(i) (i - 1) %% 3 + 1

  # The i'th component of the cross product is:
  # (x[i + 1] * y[i + 2]) - (x[i + 2] * y[i + 1])
  # as long as we treat the indices cyclically.
  return (x[Index3D(i + 1)] * y[Index3D(i + 2)] -
          x[Index3D(i + 2)] * y[Index3D(i + 1)])
}

CrossProduct2D <- function(x, y) CrossProduct3D(x, y, i=3)
```

### Does it work?

Let's check [a random example I found online](http://mathinsight.org/cross_product_examples):

```
> CrossProduct3D(c(3, -3, 1), c(4, 9, 2)) == c(-15, -2, 39)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Looks pretty good!

### Why is this better than previous answers?

- It's 3D (Carl's was 2D-only).
- It's simple and idiomatic.
- Nicely commented and formatted; hence, easy to understand

The downside is that the number '3' is hardcoded several times.  Actually, this isn't such a bad thing, since it highlights the fact that the vector cross product is *purely* a 3D construct.  Personally, I'd recommend [ditching cross products entirely](http://www.av8n.com/physics/clifford-intro.htm#preface-nocross) and [learning Geometric Algebra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123749425) instead. :)

Comment: Nice, tho' I'd take a bit of exception to the dumping cross products, since chirality is pretty important to E&M and a few other bits of physics :-)

Comment: Thanks for the kind words :)  Chirality is important, but the cross product's chirality is arbitrary. In E&M, you'd get all the same answers if you used a _left_ hand rule, since it's applied an even number of times.  See http://www.av8n.com/physics/pierre-puzzle.htm (and especially the solution) for more detail.

Answer (score 5):

The help `?crossprod` explains it quite clearly. Take linear regression for example, for a model `y = XB + e` you want to find `X'X`, the product of `X` transpose and `X`. To get that, a simple call will suffice: `crossprod(X)` is the same as `crossprod(X,X)` is the same as `t(X) %*% X`. Also, `crossprod` can be used to find the dot product of two vectors.

Comment: Yes, but that's not the definition of a cross product, as I said above.  Maybe I'm being pedantic, but I'd like a "cross product" function to produce  the result shown on the Wikipedia page (or your friendly neighborhood  Physics 101 text :-) )

Comment: I have not heard it be called a cross product except in R.

Answer (score 2):

In response to @Bryan Hanson's request, here's some Q&D code to calculate a vector crossproduct for two vectors in the plane.  It's a bit messier to calculate the general 3-space vector crossproduct, or to extend to N-space.  If you need those, you'll have to go to Wikipedia :-) .

```
crossvec <- function(x,y){
if(length(x)!=2 |length(y)!=2) stop('bad vectors')
 cv <-  x[1]*y[2]-x[2]*y[1]
return(invisible(cv))
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Carlwitthoft.  I had written pretty much just that, and was hoping you had the 3d version.  I shall write it and post it when it is ready. It's very strange that such a thing is not built in.  It's extraordinarily common.

Comment: There is a 3D version in `RFOC::cross.prod`; in the same package there a few others that accept different input and output formats.  Also, `RSEIS::xprod`.

Comment: @BryanHanson  I suspect that, while 3D crossproduct is very common in Physics and Engineering,  not so much in Statistical Analysis, which is sort of where `R` was born. Luckily, us Physicists are really good at turning equations into code :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a minimalistic implementation for 3D vectors:

```
vector.cross <- function(a, b) {
    if(length(a)!=3 || length(b)!=3){
        stop("Cross product is only defined for 3D vectors.");
    }
    i1 <- c(2,3,1)
    i2 <- c(3,1,2)
    return (a[i1]*b[i2] - a[i2]*b[i1])
}
```

If you want to get the scalar "cross product" of 2D vectors `u` and `v`, you can do

```
vector.cross(c(u,0),c(v,0))[3]
```

Comment: Except cross product **is** defined for 2D vectors so your msg is misleading.  Why not merge our answers into a single function?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I know what you mean but cross product is technically 3D. If someone wants to wrap the special case (last line of this answer) in a function it is better they name it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful math operations package named pracma (https://rdrr.io/rforge/pracma/api/ or CRAN https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pracma/index.html).
Easy to use and quick. The cross product is literally given by pracma::cross(x, y) for any two vectors.

Comment: You should provide the link to CRAN rather than dev locations.  Further, you need to identify the specific calls (functions) in `pracma` which meet the OP's needs

Comment: I edited it. I don't agree with linking to CRAN instead of the link I had, since it is much more informative and points to all the different options the package holds.