# R - Compute Cross Product of Vectors (Physics)

Tags: r, cross-product

What am I doing wrong?

```
> crossprod(1:3,4:6)
     [,1]
[1,]   32
```

According to this website:http://onlinemschool.com/math/assistance/vector/multiply1/

It should give:

```
{-3; 6; -3}
```

See also [What is R's crossproduct function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162741/what-is-rs-crossproduct-function)

Comment: that function is just `1:3 %*% 4:6`, not crossproduct in the physics sense

Comment: I'm voting to reopen, since the question seems to be about on how to do cross product in R and not about what `crossprod` does.

Comment: @nicola Nonetheless, the answers there do explain how to do cross products...

Comment: @Frank Yes, I agree on "This question already has an answer here" but not on "an exact duplicate of an existing question". Questions are clearly different. Honestly not sure whether to close it or not...

Comment: Yeah, it's fine either way. At least they're linked now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a generalized cross product:

```
xprod <- function(...) {
  args <- list(...)

  # Check for valid arguments

  if (length(args) == 0) {
    stop("No data supplied")
  }
  len <- unique(sapply(args, FUN=length))
  if (length(len) > 1) {
    stop("All vectors must be the same length")
  }
  if (len != length(args) + 1) {
    stop("Must supply N-1 vectors of length N")
  }

  # Compute generalized cross product by taking the determinant of sub-matricies

  m <- do.call(rbind, args)
  sapply(seq(len),
         FUN=function(i) {
           det(m[,-i,drop=FALSE]) * (-1)^(i+1)
         })
}
```

For your example:

```
> xprod(1:3, 4:6)
[1] -3  6 -3
```

This works for any dimension:

```
> xprod(c(0,1)) # 2d
[1] 1 0
> xprod(c(1,0,0), c(0,1,0)) # 3d
[1] 0 0 1
> xprod(c(1,0,0,0), c(0,1,0,0), c(0,0,1,0)) # 4d
[1]  0  0  0 -1
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

Comment: Thanks to G. V. Welland for the idea behind this (many years ago).

Answer (score 5):

crossprod computes a [Matrix Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Matrix_product_.28two_matrices.29). To perform a [Cross Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product), either write your function, or:

```
> install.packages("pracma") 
> require("pracma")
> cross(v1,v2)
```

if the first line above does not work, try this:

```
> install.packages("pracma", repos="https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pracma/index.html”)
```

Answer (score 3):

crossprod does the following: `t(1:3) %*% 4:6`

Therefore it is a 1x3 vector times a 3x1 vector --> a scalar

Comment: so what is this doing? http://onlinemschool.com/math/assistance/vector/multiply1/

Comment: what NBATrends is saying is that a vector of same dimensions produces a vector where if you cross product vectors of opposite dimensions you get a number. The link you provided cross products 2 vectors of similar dimensions to produce a vector result.

Comment: @Kevin Your link is related to the concept of a cross product, yes. The writers of R's predecessor, S, chose to reuse that term a different way, possibly oblivious to physics terminology.

Answer (score 3):

```
crossProduct <- function(ab,ac){
  abci = ab[2] * ac[3] - ac[2] * ab[3];
  abcj = ac[1] * ab[3] - ab[1] * ac[3];
  abck = ab[1] * ac[2] - ac[1] * ab[2];
  return (c(abci, abcj, abck))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `expand.grid`

```
expand.grid(LETTERS[1:3],letters[1:3])
```

Output:

```
 Var1 Var2
1    A    a
2    B    a
3    C    a
4    A    b
5    B    b
6    C    b
7    A    c
8    B    c
9    C    c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> v=c(1,2,3);w=c(4,5,6)
> c(v[2]*w[3]-v[3]*w[2],v[3]*w[1]-v[1]*w[3],v[1]*w[2]-v[2]*w[1])
[1] -3  6 -3
> i1=c(2,3,1);i2=c(3,1,2);v[i1]*w[i2]-v[i2]*w[i1]
[1] -3  6 -3
> pracma::cross(v,w)
[1] -3  6 -3
> sapply(1:length(v),function(i)det(rbind(v,w)[,-i])*(-1)^(i+1))
[1] -3  6 -3
```

The regular vector cross product operation is only defined in three dimensions, but the last option from the accepted answer is generalized to multiple dimensions. `pracma::cross` is implemented the same way as the first option.