# easiest way to construct an orthogonal vector in R

Tags: r, orthogonal

How would I construct an orthogonal vector to two existing vectors, `v1` and `v2`?

[Unfortunately, stackoverflow wants some more prose here or complains that it does not meet standards.]

Comment: might be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501949/determining-a-perpendicular-vector-to-two-given-vectors and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36798301/r-compute-cross-product-of-vectors-physics/36802067

Answer (score 4):

In base R, given any two vectors, the ORTHOGONAL vector can be obtained by:

```
 a <- rbind(v1, v2)
 orth.vec <- sapply(seq(ncol(a)), function(x)(-1)^(x-1)*det(a[,-x]))
```

if you need to normalize it, ie the orthonormal vector:

```
 orth.vec/norm(orth.vec,"2")
```

EDIT:
Note that this code is the same whether given n vectors. ie `a` must be a matrix of dimensions: `n x (n + 1)`

eg: Compare the two results below:

```
a <- matrix(sample(90),9)
MASS::Null(t(a))
             [,1]
 [1,] -0.16836356
 [2,] -0.41335337
 [3,]  0.55917161
 [4,] -0.36823759
 [5,] -0.16845300
 [6,]  0.29331428
 [7,]  0.09284215
 [8,]  0.10840769
 [9,] -0.13890032
[10,]  0.44547280

get_orth_vec <- function(y)sapply(seq(ncol(y)), function(x)(-1)^(x-1)*det(y[,-x]))

# Unnormalized Orthogonal Vector
orth.vec <- get_orth_vec(a)
 [1]  2.418607e+15  5.937980e+15 -8.032715e+15  5.289874e+15  2.419892e+15 -4.213572e+15 -1.333713e+15
 [8] -1.557318e+15  1.995356e+15 -6.399388e+15
 # Orthonormal vector
 orth.vec/norm(orth.vec,"2")
 [1]  0.16836356  0.41335337 -0.55917161  0.36823759  0.16845300 -0.29331428 -0.09284215 -0.10840769
 [9]  0.13890032 -0.44547280
```

Note that the only difference between the two is the direction.
If you have larger matrices, use the packages since they use the qr decomposition

Comment: Nice answer with home-made recipe, +1!

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way may well be an abuse of the ols model:

```
orthogonal.vector <- resid( lm( rnorm(length(v1)) ~ v1 + v2 ) )
```

example:

```
> v1 <- rnorm(5); v2 <- rnorm(5);
> orthogonal.vector <- resid( lm( rnorm(length(v1)) ~ v1 + v2 ) )
> orthogonal.vector %*% v1
                       [,1]
[1,] -0.0000000000000004441
> orthogonal.vector %*% v2
                     [,1]
[1,] 0.000000000000000111
```

> 

Comment: Technically this is not quite correct. c(0,0,0) is the origin rather than an orthogonal vector

Comment: please elaborate.  the result is not the origin.

Comment: Because you generated randomly, but residuals need to be zero. If the model is a perfect fit, the residuals are zero. Try it again

Comment: got it.  s perfectly fit model y is a zero-probability event, though, for a randomly drawn y vector.  and in this case, one can just redo it with another randomly drawn vector.

Comment: I tried 5 times and all of them i got the residuals to be c(0,0,0). This is not an orthogonal vector

Comment: I am guessing that your vectors already exhaust the space (i.e., you have two-dimensional vectors).  you can only find a new orthogonal vector to both if you have more dimensions than vectors.  I have added an example.

Comment: What is the meaning of residuals to you?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `null` from `pracma` package, e.g.,

```
vout <- pracma::null(M)
```

or `Null` from `MASS`, e.g.,

```
vout <- MASS::Null(t(M))
```

such that

```
> M%*%vout
            [,1]
v1 -2.220446e-16
v2  4.440892e-16
```

**Data**

```
v1 <- c(1,2,3)
v2 <- c(3,2,4)
M <- rbind(v1,v2)
```