# Matrix operation efficiency in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have 3 matrices X, K and M as follows.

```
x <- matrix(c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),ncol=3)
K <- matrix(c(4,5,4,5,4,5),ncol=3) 
M <- matrix(c(0.1,0.2,0.3),ncol=1)
```

Here is what I need to accomplish.

For example,

```
Y(1,1)=(1-4)^2*0.1^2+(1-4)^2*0.2^2+(1-4)^2*0.3^2
Y(1,2)=(1-5)^2*0.1^2+(1-5)^2*0.2^2+(1-5)^2*0.3^2
...
Y(3,2)=(3-5)^2*0.1^2+(3-5)^2*0.2^2+(3-5)^2*0.3^2
```

Currently I used 3 for loops to calculate the final matrix in R. But for large matrices, this is taking extremely long to calculate. And I also need to change the elements in matrix M to find the best value that produces minimal squared errors. Is there a better way to code it up, i.e. Euclidean norm?

```
for (lin in 1:N) {
  for (col in 1:K) {
    Y[lin,col] <- 0
    for (m in 1:M){
      Y[lin,col] <- Y[lin,col] + (X[lin,m]-K[col,m])^2 * M[m,1]^2
    }
  }
}
```

Edit:

I ended up using Rcpp to write the code in C++ and call it from R. It is significantly faster! It takes 2-3 seconds to fill up a 2000 * 2000 matrix.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake explaining things earlier. I made some updates and hopefully I explained myself better this time.

Comment: What was the N object? - I can't get this code to run. And how big is your large matrices?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933945/how-to-calculate-the-euclidean-norm-of-a-vector-in-r

Comment: Thanks! I was able to figure it out. I made up this example. My real data has 1 million records. I suppose the code didn't run probably because N,K and M need to be defined earlier.

Comment: Happy to have helped a little! Mark your own answer as the  correct one to close the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I was able to figure this out. The change made my calculation twice as fast as before. For anyone who may be interested, I replaced the last for loop `for(m in 1:M)` with the following:

```
Y[lin,col] <- norm(as.matrix((X[lin,]-K[col,]) * M[1,]),"F")^2
```

Note that I transposed the matrix M so that it has 3 columns instead of 1.